# Continuous bijection between compacts of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, compactness

Is it possible to find continuous bijection between $[0;1]$ and any compact $E \subset \mathbb{R}$?
And more generally between $[0;1]^n$ and any compact $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

$\mathbb{R}^n$ has a finite dimension so the compact set are the closed and bounded set of $\mathbb{R}^n,$ can we deduce from this the above result?

Comment: The continuous image of a connected set is connected but there are non connected compact sets while $[0, 1]$ is connected, so no.

Comment: No, those must be homeomorphisms.

Comment: Just to expand on what berci and I said, they must be homeomorphisms since the continuous bijection from a compact space to a hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. There are non connected compact subsets and $[0, 1]$ is connected, so not possible

Comment: And of course there are countable compact subsets of $\Bbb R$, with which there isn’t even a bijection, let alone a continuous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider a set, which consists of one point.